# Ulam Spiral, what angle does x fall on?

Tags: circles, solid-angle

Morning all,

I'm trying to work out what angle a given number will fall on within the Ulam Spiral.

The formula I have so far is this:
$$ \dfrac{180 \times\sqrt{x}-255}{360} $$

For example using $x= 49$ we have $\sqrt{49}= 7$, $7 \times 180 = 1260$; $1260 - 225 = 1035$; $1035 / 360 = 2.875$

This tells me that $49$ is $2.875$ rotations from the centre. To find the angle, I take the decimal $0.875$ and multiply by $360$, giving me $315$ degrees. This works for any number that falls on the $315$ degree, e.g. $9, 25, 49, 81$ etc.

The problem is, this doesn't work for any number that doesn't sit on the $315$ angle.  I have feeling that this is to do with using $225$, but I don't know where this number comes from or what formula I should use to work this out.

You may have guessed that I'm not a mathematician, so please be gentle!

Many thanks

Pete

Comment: How have you found your formula?

Comment: Hi Emilio,not yet. Thanks for asking.

Comment: I think @EmilioNovati is referring to $$\alpha =360\left\{\frac{180\sqrt{x}-225}{360}\right\}$$where $\{x\}=x-\left\lfloor x\right\rfloor$, or "mantissa" of $x$; as your explanation stated in words. "How did you come up to this equation" or "how have you found this formula" are equivalent ;)

Comment: Hi Andrea, I didn't see the "How" in Emilio's response! I found this formula through the power of Google. As mentioned, I'm no mathematician, so apologise if I'm not explaining things clearly. I'm doing a bit of personnal research into this, to look for relationships between certain numbers that are a number of degrees apart, or 360 degrees either side. Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

To find angle of a number, (in this example of ulam spiral, starts 1 in the center and run clockwise, ie # 2 Left, #4 Up, #6 right, #8 down)

Step 1: - Need to locate the number that belongs to which spiral (or in which ring ) for Example 57 belongs to 4th ring.
Formula for finding ring number is as follows
= ROUND((SQRT(57)−0.22)÷2,0) = 4

Step 2: - To find angle of any number, first we need to locate 'zero degree'
number in that particular ring,
(for example 'zero degree' number in ring 4 = 53).
Formula for find 'zero degree' number is as follows
=((Ring number × 2)+1)^2−(7× 'Ring number') = 'Zero degree' number

Step 3: - To find angle of any number (in Ulam spiral), formula is as
follows,
= SUM((Number − 'Zero Degree Number') ÷ ( Ring number ÷ 45))
= Sum ((57 − 53) ÷ (4 ÷ 45)) = 45 Degrees [Number Spiral of 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3wki.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).